# Laravel withCount use function in model

Tags: php, laravel

I have model Post:

```
 protected $guarded = [];

 public function reviews() {
      return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
 }
```

My reviews table have a column type with values: 1(good),2(comment),3(negative).
I need get count reviews for every type. I need globally get these counts. I know that I can do in model something like this:

```
 protected $withCount = ['reviews'];
```

But this get me all reviews. But I need get count only for every type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `withCount` method and do sub queries inside:

```
$counts = Post::withCount([
'reviews',
'reviews as good_reviews' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 1);
}],
'reviews as bad_reviews' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 3);
}],

}])->get();
```

You can access the count like this:

```
echo $counts[0]->good_reviews;
```

For more info: [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

you can use GroupBy method for it.

Something like this:

```
DB::table('reviews')
             ->select('type', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('type')
             ->get();
```